# R: Remove string from within another string?

Tags: r, string, replace

I have data that looks like

```
Var1
----------------------
text 1 (str to remove)
----------------------
text 2 (str to remove)
----------------------
text 3 (str to remove)
----------------------
```

I want to remove

```
" (str to remove)"
```

So that the output looks like

```
Var1
----------------------
text 1
----------------------
text 2
----------------------
text 3
----------------------
```

I have tried gsub and str_replace but I guess they only work with regex patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) followed by the `(` and the rest of the characters (`.*`) and replace with blank for the 'Var1' column and assign back to the data

```
df1$Var1 <- sub("\\s+\\(.*", "", df1$Var1)
```

If the string is fixed, then we can also do

```
df1$Var1 <- sub(" (str to remove)", "", df1$Var1, fixed = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("text 1 (str to remove)", 
"text 2 (str to remove)", 
"text 3 (str to remove)")), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```